# Background CSS image no showing in IE7 only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

The html is:

```
<div class="choose-os">
<p>
   <a href="someLink" class="windows">Microsoft Windows</a> 
   <a href="someOtherLink" class="macos">Apple Mac OS</a>
</p>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.choose-os {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #e7eefa;
}
.choose-os p {
    margin: 0;
}
.choose-os p a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -100000px;
    height: 56px;
    width: 308px;
}
.choose-os p a.windows {
    background: url(../images/button-windows-bg.png) 0 0;
}
.choose-os p a.macos {
    background: url(../images/button-macos-bg.png) 0 0;
}
.choose-os p a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -56px;
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as to have the background image also appear on IE7.

Comment: The live webpage is: http://www.landlordmax.com/downloads

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `text-indent: -100000px;` in combination with `inline-block` is what's causing the two elements to not be visible in IE7, due to a bug.

You need to find some other way to hide the text for IE7 (or not use `inline-block` at all, see below for this more suitable fix).

Options include the method in the comment by @Sotiris, or:

```
.choose-os p a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 56px;
    width: 308px;

    text-indent: -100000px;

    /* for ie7 */
    *text-indent: 0;
    *font-size: 0;
    *line-height: 0
}
```

Which uses the `*property: value` hack several times to hide the text in IE7.

---

The problem does seem to be related to the use of `display: inline-block`.

So, another workaround (*which I prefer to my previous one*) is:

```
.choose-os {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #e7eefa;
    overflow: hidden
}
.choose-os p a {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    text-indent: -100000px;
    height: 56px;
    width: 308px;
}
```

Comment: +1 propably he want's to hide the text, wrapping it with a `span` and then `.choose-os span {display:none}` will do the trick, but I don't know if `display:none` affects SEO

Comment: @Stephane Grenier: My first one works: http://jsbin.com/ogelam/3. So does the second one: http://jsbin.com/ogelam/4. *(see both in IE7, and look in the source code just before `</head>`)*. It might not be working for you due to the CSS inside `.inner .maincontent .choose-os p a`. Make sure you're also checking that.

Comment: It looks like you're right, there must be something in the .inner .maincontent css code. I have no idea even where to even start looking for that (one of my weaknesses is css). I just published the new css code to the website even if it's still not displaying in IE7 because at least it's part of the way...

Comment: Also thank you since I forgot to mention it before!! In Firefox you can just use Firebug and edit on the fly, but with IE7 there's no such mechanism that I know. Which means you really have to understand CSS in detail to figure out such a bug. Ugh...

Comment: @Stephane Grenier you can use internet explorer developer tools or firebug lite http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: Nevermind, it's working now. I was using SuperPreview to view IE7 but for whatever reason it wasn't refreshing. It's only when I went to VMWare that it started to properly refresh and now everything is displaying correctly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

To display `inline-block` properly in IE7, add the following styles to `.choose-os p a`

```
zoom:1
*display:inline
```

(The star is important! It's ignored by modern browsers, but not IE6/7)

IE7 doesn't respect inline-block, so you have to do a little magic to make it work. There's a great description here: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

[edit] If text-indent is also part of the culprit, you may be better of sticking with `display:block` and setting `float:left` on your elements. Probably multiple valid paths to take :)

Comment: `inline-block` works in IE7, provided the element has a default style of `inline` (which `a` does, of course). This hack is only required if the element you're styling has a default style of `block`.

Comment: Fair enough. Floating the elements is still the better solution; `inline-block` just jumped out at me.

Answer (score -1):

IE7 has some serious limitations in CSS.  I would recommend avoiding the shorthand notation and explicitly declaring each property, then validate the CSS sheet [here](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).