# css ie6 sprities image not showing using inline-block

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-sprites

images is not showing, when i use inline-block for ie6.

```
.img {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image:url(../sprites-8.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
    text-indent:-7000px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; /* zoom and *display = ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
    *display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-indent:-7000px;` is the problem.

See this *similar* question for more information: [Background CSS image no showing in IE7 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726312/background-css-image-no-showing-in-ie7-only)

Answer (score 0):

Put `*display: inline` in a separate definition block.

```
.img {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image:url(../sprites-8.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
    text-indent:-7000px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; /* zoom and *display = ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
}
.img {
    *display: inline;
}
```